# Why the column getting merged after exporting in excel in Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, merge, telerik

I am using telerik reports in Asp.net,
In which after exporting data into excel, Some of the column is getting merged (Column Value length < 10 char) .

Can any one suggest why the value is not placed into single column only , 
why the column is getting merged?

Is there any option in telerik report, where I can stop merging the column.

Comment: Are you using Telerik RadGrid for this report?

Comment: NO, We don't using RadGrid in Report page. As the report is generated it contains collection of textbox.

You can check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmX_cZDcKXA)

Count(Source column)=Count(textbox on Report Grid)